# Hitting Ctrl-Z in emacs freezes everything

Tags: emacs

I'm using Linux, and alternate between emacs and sublime text. In sublime text, Ctrl-Z is undo. This means sometimes I sometimes hit Ctrl-Z in emacs; unfortunately when I do this, the whole process simply freezes. I assume this has to do with the typical Ctrl-Z behavior of suspending a process; however I'm running Emacs in a GUI, so why it would have this behavior is a bit beyond me. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: How about disabling that Emacs keyboard shortcut so that hitting it does nothing, instead of the default key-binding of `(suspend-frame)`?:  `(define-key global-map "\C-z" nil)`  NOTE:  You should check to see what `C-z` is bound to with `C-h k C-z` because it's possible another major or minor mode has a different keyboard assignment.

Comment: That would work in this case; however when I'm running it in the terminal I do want to be able to suspend the process. Is there a way to switch on that behavior?

Comment: The default settings for the Emacs Trunk (October 2014) that I am using has two (2) different bindings:  `[suspend-frame] is bound to C-z, C-x C-z.`  So you can still use the latter; or, create your own new binding.  You can always activate an *interactive* command with `M-x suspend-frame RET`

Comment: In GUI Emacs, `suspend-frame` typically minimises the GUI window. Do you have any thoughts on why that might not be occurring in your environment? What is your specific OS and window manager?

Comment: I'm using i3, which is a tiling WM, so it could be there's something with minimization and weirdness. Binding Ctrl-Z to nil worked though.

Comment: @limp_chimp, I also use i3 and I just tested `C-z`. You're right, it does freeze Emacs. But switching focus away from Emacs (e.g. by focusing another window, or switching to another workspace) and back, Emacs wakes up just like nothing ever happened. Do you get different behaviour?

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest the following over simply disabling the binding entirely:

```el
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-z"))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-z C-z") 'my-suspend-frame)

(defun my-suspend-frame ()
  "In a GUI environment, do nothing; otherwise `suspend-frame'."
  (interactive)
  (if (display-graphic-p)
      (message "suspend-frame disabled for graphical displays.")
    (suspend-frame)))
```

Or you *could* just bind the function directly to `C-z`, but I find it super-useful to open up that as a prefix binding for other commands -- given how very infrequently I actually need to call `suspend-frame`, I find a double `C-z C-z` just as convenient.